# Discord.py simple login client

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

This is simple client bot using client token, but i am facing problem

```
import discord
from decimal import Decimal
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
load_dotenv()
my_var = os.environ['TOKEN']
print(my_var)
print(type(m))
@client.event
async def on_ready():

    print('Bot Have Logged In as {0.user'.format(client))


# (webpackChunkdiscord_app.push([[''],{},e=>{m=[];for(let c in e.c)m.push(e.c[c])}]),m).find(m=>m?.exports?.default?.getToken!==void 0).exports.default.getToken()


client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

[2023-09-08 02:11:36] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\MrSufi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 803, in static_login
data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MrSufi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 745, in request
raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\MrSufi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\text.py", line 15, in 
client.run(TOKEN)
File "C:\Users\MrSufi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 860, in run
asyncio.run(runner())
File "C:\Users\MrSufi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
return runner.run(main)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MrSufi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MrSufi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MrSufi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 849, in runner
await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
File "C:\Users\MrSufi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 777, in start
await self.login(token)
File "C:\Users\MrSufi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 612, in login
data = await self.http.static_login(token)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\MrSufi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 807, in static_login
raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.

I have tried everything but still facing this.

I have tried everything but still facing the problem.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? The error means that the token provided is not valid so reset your bot token on the developer page.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues with the code you pasted, but maybe it's incomplete?

1. You're printing `print(type(m))`, but `m` was never defined.
2. You have created two instances of `discord.Intents.default()`, which is redundant. You can create one, assign it to a variable and use it later when needed.
3. There's a typo at the `print` statement within `on_ready()`
4. You're loading the Token with `load_dotenv()`, and then assigning the bot token to a variable `my_var` using `os.environ['TOKEN']`. This is, by itself, correct; however, there's a problem with the subsequent code when you call `client.run(...)`. You can either call it using the variable you defined `client.run(my_var)`, or using the token you loaded from `load_dotenv()` `client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))`

Below are two working examples using both scenarios described in item 4, I have also removed any unnecessary code.

Using `os.environ`:

```py
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
intents.messages = True

load_dotenv()
my_var = os.environ['TOKEN']

@client.event
async def on_ready():

    print('Bot Have Logged In as {0.user}'.format(client))

client.run(my_var)
```

Using `load_dotenv`:

```py
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
intents.messages = True

load_dotenv()

@client.event
async def on_ready():

    print('Bot Have Logged In as {0.user}'.format(client))

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```